# Can I ask a question with a second title?

Tags: discussion, questions, title

I just have posted this question in Unix & Linux, I don't know if its title fits the rule: [Failed to get canonical path of `/tmp/kcm-grub2-0/boot/grub'. (Grub2 Bootloader can't access Windows 8 because it is hibernated)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155524/60602)

Initially, I get trouble with booting Windows 8. After trying to solve this, I learn that I need to get the canonical path, and I stuck in this. I don't know if I can add the second title in that case. It will clarify the question, in my opinion.

If the answer is yes, should SE has an option to add a second title when asking question?

---

As nhahtdh states:

> If it is a separate problem, ask in a separate question. If it belongs
>   to a step inside the current problem, ask the answerer in the comment.

I know that. Let's look at the question in Unix & Linux again. I just have found the solution that solve the main problem (problem with Grub2 Bootloader) but **not** the main question (failed to get canonical path). That means I may not need to care about the canonical path anymore, but the question about it still remain. Maybe there is another problem need to solve the canonical path directly, and my answer is not able to do that.

---

My other question: [How to write Vietnamese names in English correctly? (“Việt Nam” to “Vietnam” or “Viet Nam”?)](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/196871/80007Z)

Comment: If it is a separate problem, ask in a separate question. If it belongs to a step inside the current problem, ask the answerer in the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that what I mean is a **variation** of the question. It's similar to the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/260800). I guess it's fine to have parentheses in the title.

Answer (score 12):

If your new problem is a separate problem, post a brand new question. This keeps the current question clean and allows for simple answers. Modifying the original question with a brand new problem could, potentially, invalidate existing answers.

If your new problem is a step within the existing problem, modify the original post to include the new data and results. It is worth while to comment to answerers that you've updated the question to include this data as well. They may be able to assist you with your next steps.

Comment: Good answer, but be aware that a rework of the question that will invalidate the answers already there is not a very good option. If those answers pushed you in the right direction, accept that and ask a new question, referring to your original one.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please come and see.